# Styling a disabled range input

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm have range inputs styled with

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #2C65FF;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #2C65FF;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #2C65FF;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: -14px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: white;
}
```

I'd like to give them a "greyed out" style when they're disabled.
Just tacking on a `:disabled` on to each of the existing selectors with a darkened background does not seem to be doing anything.

How can I style a disabled range input?

Comment: This doesn't work? `input[type="range"]:disabled {` Probably needs the quotes.

Comment: see my Answer below, its what you looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to add on the other css props like this:

```
input[type=range]:disabled {
    /* Disabled Element */
}

input[type=range]:disabled::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    /* Disabled slider-runnable-track */
}

input[type=range]:disabled::-moz-range-track {
      /* Disabled slider-range-track */
}

input[type=range]:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    /* Disabled slider-thumb */
}

input[type=range]:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {
    /* Disabled slider-thumb */
}
```

Example: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6g71ds2a/2/)

**notice**

> ":disabled" followed by "::-propertyname"

Comment: Sure enough! For reference of anyone who comes later, the difference was that before I had ::-propertyname followed by :disabled, and it needed to be the other way around.